# How do I use Play2 Iteratees to consume streaming HTTP with different event names?

Tags: scala, playframework, functional-programming, streaming, loops

I want a functional way of consuming server-sent events (SSE) over HTTP (or streaming HTTP as some call it). Through examples ([Scala: Receiving Server-Sent-Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703099/scala-receiving-server-sent-events)) I've found that Play2 Iteratees work well with its WS client when the event name is set to "message." Here is what the "message" stream looks like:

```
GET http://streaming.server.com/temperature

event: message
data: {"room":"room1","temp":71,"time":"2015-05-06T00:23:10.203+02:00"}

event: message
data: {"room":"room1","temp":70,"time":"2015-05-06T00:31:18.873+02:00"}
...
```

And here's what my web client looks like:

```
import com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder
import play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee
import play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution.Implicits.defaultExecutionContext
import play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingWSClient

object Client extends App {
  val client = new NingWSClient(new Builder().build())
  def print = Iteratee.foreach { chunk: Array[Byte] => println(new String(chunk)) }
  client.url("http://streaming.server.com/temperature").get(_ => print)
}
```

with some output that it printed to my console:

```
$ sbt run
[info] Running Client 
data: {"room":"room1","temp": 70, "time":"2015-05-06T00:31:14.193+02:00"}
data: {"room":"room1","temp": 70, "time":"2015-05-06T00:31:18.873+02:00"}
...
```

But when I set "event" to some other value than "message" the Iteratee immediately returns the `Done` signal just after reading the first value and then stops the stream. The spec I'm required to satisfy uses `"event":"put"`. Below is an example of what the "put" stream looks like:

```
GET http://streaming.server.com/temperature

event: put
data: {"room":"room1","temp":71,"time":"2015-05-06T00:39:14.281+02:00"}

event: put
data: {"room":"room1","temp":70,"time":"2015-05-06T00:39:18.778+02:00"}
...
```

I discovered this when I added an `onComplete()` handler at the end and matched on a `Success` case like so:

```
client.url("http://streaming.server.com/temperature").get(_ => print).onComplete {
  case Success(s) => println(s)
  case Failure(s) => println(f.getMessage)
}
```

This code now prints:

```
$ sbt run
[info] Running Client
data: {"room":"room1","temp": 71, "time":"2015-05-06T00:39:14.281+02:00"}
Done((),Empty)
```

So far, I've only had success with the [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/sse.html) library for Java whose semantics is very similar to the EventSource JavaScript client; however it doesn't compose and appears to only support single-threaded consumption of SSEs. I would much rather use the Play2 WS+Iteratee libraries. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you considered using something like Akka Streams & HTTP instead?

Comment: I've dabbled with it, but since it's still experimental I'm reluctant to thoroughly embrace it for production-grade code. It looks promising though, just waiting for it to mature.